# Query gathering the max value of a subquery returning multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, selection

I've encountered another problem with SQL queries on Oracle Database, which I'm not able to solve. I have 3 tables, two of them gathering information on some users and structures, and another one gathering bookings for a structure. Thanks to a query, I should be able to display the name of the user who made the **maximum number of bookings for a structure in a specific city**, in this case 'Torre annunziata'.

For achieving this, I've created a query whose objective is to display a table which show, for every user, the amount of bookings he did for the structure I've previously mentioned.

```
SELECT P.UTENTE, COUNT(Case when S.Citta = 'Torre Annunziata' then 1 else null end) as cnt
FROM PRENOTAZIONI P JOIN STRUTTURE S ON P.STRUTTURA = S.CODICE JOIN UTENTI ON P.UTENTE = UTENTI.CF
GROUP BY P.UTENTE;
```

This giving the desired result: [table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwpPi.png)

Now I've tried the following:

```
SELECT UTENTI.NOME, UTENTI.COGNOME, MAX(cnt)
FROM UTENTI JOIN ( SELECT P.UTENTE, COUNT(Case when S.Citta = 'Torre Annunziata' then 1 else null end) as cnt
                    FROM PRENOTAZIONI P JOIN STRUTTURE S ON P.STRUTTURA = S.CODICE JOIN UTENTI ON P.UTENTE = UTENTI.CF
                    GROUP BY P.UTENTE) L ON UTENTI.CF = L.UTENTE
GROUP BY UTENTI.COGNOME, UTENTI.NOME;
```

But this return the same result of the previous query (with the names of each person).

Based on my request, the result I'm expecting is the name and the surname of user 0000000002, possibly without max value being displayed.

I know that MAX function return the value for each user, and therefore I searched for alternatives for oracle, but I can't find the solution which could be applied to my problem. I hope someone will be able to help me.
Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want aggregation.  Use window functions instead.  If you want ties:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM UTENTI u JOIN
     (SELECT P.UTENTE, u.NOME, u.COGNOME, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM PRENOTAZIONI P JOIN
           STRUTTURE S
           ON P.STRUTTURA = S.CODICE JOIN
           UTENTI u
           ON P.UTENTE = u.CF
      WHERE S.Citta = 'Torre Annunziata'
      GROUP BY P.UTENTE, u.NOME, u.COGNOME
     ) u
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Notes:

- You do not need to `JOIN` the table `UTENTI` twice.
- The filtering condition can go in the `WHERE` clause.
- Use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()` if you want exactly one row, even when there are ties.

Comment: This works as expected, except I needed to change the last part where the ON keyword was expected by the JOIN. I double joined because the program couldn't recognize UTENTI table. I filtered COUNT function because I had to do a similar query, and filtering with WHERE clause excluded 0 results from query, whereas I needed them to show up. Finally, thanks for clarifying the aim of RANK function and for solving the problem.